# Links to user defined functions in an add-in

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, add-in

I've created an add-in with a bunch of user defined functions.
Whenever I send the workbook that contains these functions there is a problem with links on each cell using these functions.

And yes, I've also sent the add-in to the other user and made sure he had installed it before open my workbook.

[image]

Does the user have to install the add-in in the exactly same location I do? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it has to be in the exact same location that the link refersto: this is a limitation of the way VBA UDFs are implemented.

Comment: By any chance, is there a way to add the formula as a relative reference instead of a absolute one, pointing to the default excel add-in's directory name?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the formula in a *.xlam and deploy that in the Excel Addins folder.

This should obviate the need for absolute path of the XLAM file.